# Delay when between slides with audio

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I'm putting together a power point presentation that I have precise audio behind that matches up with when the slides move. However, after I rehearse my timings, the rehearsed time is anywhere between 4-8 seconds shorter than the length of the three minute audio file, and when I go to play the slideshow to check what happened, the slides advance before I had rehearsed them to. In addition, the slideshow is cut off by 4-8 seconds for whatever reason. I have no transitions, just audio in the first slide that plays continuously across the slides.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint has never been able to accurately play back presentations timed against a soundtrack.

Sometimes it helps to run through the show once before playing it to your audience, but obviously that's practical only in rare situations.

If you can do w/o animations, you can export the slides to e.g. JPG or PNG images then use those in a movie maker program (Windows Live Moviemaker, for example), apply transitions and such there, then add the soundtrack and time the transitions to it.